# Finding the month between a range

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datasource that returns dates and I have to find where the months falls within the month and day range buckets. The months and day range buckets are predefined so I put it in a Dictionary (not sure if that is even a good idea). I am using linq to find the min and Max dates and extracting the month from them. I need to find month from the dictionary where that month extracted falls within the range. For Example

```
  Dictionary<int, int> MonthDayBuckets = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 3,31 }, { 6,30 }, { 9,30 }, { 12,31 } };

  var MinyDate = _dataSource.Min(x => x.values[0]);
  var MaxDate = _dataSource.Max(x => x.values[0]);

  var startMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(MinyDate).ToString("MM");
  var endMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate).ToString("MM");
```

Say startmonth return Jan so I want to be able to go to the dictionary and return only march (03.31) and if I get 10 for the Max (October) I am trying to return (12,31) December

Comment: In other words, do you mean you're looking for the earliest date that follows the first of a given month?

Comment: How exactly is Oct(10) , in the same range as (12,31) ? why not (9,30) ?

Comment: @AnuViswan the range is 9/30 to 12/31 the month of October falls between that range

Comment: @Jacob so I probably didnt explain it well. I will get back a date say Jan or Feb for the min date. I need to know what range that jan feb date falls into one of those predefined month and day range. So in the case of Jan and Feb it would be march 31st since that date is between 12/31 and 3/31

Comment: @AC25 That means date range has been stored in `MonthDayBuckets`. Perhaps not a good idea. Why cannot you store date itself to define range?

Comment: If I understood correctly the question is "Finding the range for a given month"

Comment: @MKR as I said not sure about that part just trying it out so Im not married to it. What do you suggest a list of dates

Comment: @AC25 Probably yes. And I would have preferred a `list/array` so that I could sort it.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, your `MonthDayBuckets` variable is meant to represent date ranges:

- 3/31 - 6/30
- 6/30 - 9/30
- 9/30 - 12/31
- 12/31 - 3/31

...and given a month, you're wanting to see what the *end date* is of the interval that the first of that month falls between? Like you gave the example of October returning `12/31`.

This problem can be simplified since you'll get the same result saying "what's the next occurring date after this given date?" The next occurring date for `10/01` would be `12/31`. So here's how you could rearrange your data:

```
var availableDates = new List<string> { "03/31", "06/30", "09/30", "12/31" };
```

Now you'll be able to find a match by finding the index of the first one that's greater than your given date. Note how I made the month/day combos lexicographical orderable.

```
var startMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(MinyDate).ToString("MM");
var startDate = startMonth + "/01";
var endMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate).ToString("MM");
var endDate = endMonth + "/01";

// Wrap around to the first date if this falls after the end
var nextStartDate = availableDates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.CompareTo(startDate) >= 1) ?? availableDates[0];
var nextEndDate = availableDates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.CompareTo(endDate) >= 1) ?? availableDates[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq for the purpose. For example,

```
 var nearestKey = MonthDayBuckets.Keys.Where(x => x >= endMonth.Month).Min();
 var nearestDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,nearestKey,MonthDayBuckets[nearestKey]); // or whatever the year it needs to be represent
```

Though above query would get you the result, I would suggest you define a structure to store the Range itself, rather than using Dictionary

For example,

```
public class Range
{
    public MonthDate StartRange{get;set;}
    public MonthDate EndRange{get;set;}
    public Range(MonthDate startRange,MonthDate endRange)
    {
        StartRange = startRange;
        EndRange = endRange;
    }
}
public class MonthDate
{
    public MonthDate(int month,int date)
    {
        Month = month;
        Date = date;
    }
    public int Month{get;set;}
    public int Date{get;set;}

    //Depending on if your Ranges are inclusive or not,you need to decide how to compare
    public static bool operator >=(MonthDate source, MonthDate comparer)  
    {
        return source.Month>= comparer.Month && source.Date>=comparer.Date;
    }

    public static bool operator <=(MonthDate source, MonthDate comparer)
    {
        return source.Month<= comparer.Month && source.Date<=comparer.Date;
    }
}
```

Now you could define ranges as

```
 var dateRanges = new Range[]
     {
        new Range(new MonthDate(12,31),new MonthDate(3,31)),
        new Range(new MonthDate(3,31),new MonthDate(6,30)),
        new Range(new MonthDate(6,30),new MonthDate(12,31)),
     };
var result = dateRanges.First(x=>x.StartRange <= new MonthDate(endMonth.Month,endMonth.Day) && x.EndRange >= new MonthDate(endMonth.Month,endMonth.Day));
```